# How to resolve error: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing json to Protobuf of schema syntax = "proto3";

Tags: apache-kafka, protocol-buffers, confluent-schema-registry

I am trying to produce a message through kafka-protobuf-console-producer in kafka cli.

Command:

```
/usr/bin/kafka-protobuf-console-producer    --topic demoTopic    --broker-list vmcap00-stg.corp.netapp.com:9092    --property schema.registry.url=http://vmcap78-stg.corp.netapp.com:8081 --property value.schema.id="1"
```

Message:

```
{"eventVersion": 0.1, "producedBy": "ASUP_PUT", "asupSubject": "HA Group Notification from CH-GV1-NETAPP-01-01 (MetroCluster IP Statistics) NOTICE", "sysSerialNo": 2120063, "systemId": 05381443, "rawAsupPath": "/asupmail/asups/put/2022090061.3866.7z.headers", "completedTimestamp": 1659949215035, "sourceQueue": "PUT", "addOnAttributes": {"asupSecureType": "OTHERS", "sesgFlag": "False"}}
```

Error:

> org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error
> deserializing json to Protobuf of schema syntax = "proto3";

This is the schema being used

```
syntax = "proto3";

message SearchRequest {
  float eventVersion = 1;
  string producedBy = 2;
  string asupSubject = 3;
  int64 sysSerialNo = 4;
  int64 systemId = 5;
  string rawAsupPath = 6;
  int64 completedTimestamp = 7;
  string sourceQueue = 8;
  .SearchRequest.addonattributes addOnAttributes = 9;

  message addonattributes {
    string asupSecureType = 1;
    string sesgFlag = 2;
  }
}
```

How to resolve the issue? Thanks.